# JSON Webservice calling repeatedly iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, json, web-services, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I have two webservices (JSON), one is called at the ViewDidLoad and it returned a array of values and loaded into Array1. And I need to call another webservice, by parsing each values of Array1. I tried something like this:

```
for (pointer=0; pointer<=[Array1 count]; pointer++) {
    NSString *test = [Array1 objectAtIndex:pointer];
    NSString *urlString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://service=%@",test];
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString2]];
    connection2 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request2 delegate:self]; 
}
```

How to call this function to load the output into an array?
 A help will be much appreciated..
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown how you are executing the NSURLRequests requests you created within your loop. If you are trying to call them synchronously, then you can do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (pointer=0; pointer<=[Array1 count]; pointer++) {
    NSString *test = [Array1 objectAtIndex:pointer];
    NSString *urlString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://service=%@",test];
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString2]];
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *currentResult = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request2 returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    [result addObject:currentResult];
}
return result;
```

If instead you are trying to call the request asynchronously using self as the delegate, then you will have to do some trickier work here because all of your responses for all of your requests will come in to the same delegate. It's possible but you may want to define a dedicated objects to act as delegates for each individual request in this case...

Comment: hi Tim, thanks for the reply. i'm using the delegate methods - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
}, - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {}, - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {}, and - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection { }  I tried with your code, but it returned a different output like "7b224765 74446561 6c446574 61696c73 52657375 ", so how can I get my data? any idea?

Comment: The code sample I added returned results as NSData objects. To make it useful you will need to "decode" it appropriately for the data being returned. For example, if the data is a UTF-8 encoded JSON string you would do NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];